Insert dds messages into Elasticsearch and Kibana
I was trying to connect an Elasticsearch data base to DDs messages so I could visualize them in Kibana, and I'm trying to understand if i can create a visual that can be updated on a live stream or if it just stores the data and do I need to refresh each time I want to see the new values
And if you have a good tutorial for how to build an Elasticsearch+Kibana.
I expect to get the DDs messages into Kibana via live stream to see the chart updated with each coming message.
